# Is it possible to remove unneeded space from the X-axis in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I created a line chart in Power BI, but Power BI added white spaces to the right of the x-axis. My data only goes as far to -1 in the x-axis. Is there a way to remove the unneeded space to the right of the graph?

[image]